# how to get a dominant color from an image for expo apps

Tags: reactjs, colors, expo, native

I search a library to get the dominant color from an image that works with expo apps. I tried with **all** libs I manage to find, but each one of them were not working with **expo app**...
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get it working??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you tried [react-native-image-colors](https://github.com/osamaqarem/react-native-image-colors) then you have to make sure you configured `expo-dev-client`
[as in the expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/development/getting-started/#installing--expo-dev-client--in-your-project) for this package to work.

Comment: Hi, can you help me out with the configuration i keep getting null is not an object